# Replace all occurrences of specific character in the first line of text with regex

Tags: java, regex, regex-group

I have to grab the character `;` in the first line of a TXT.

Example of TXT:

```
abcd ; 123 ; 05/03/2020 ; maria ; 1050126584 ; efghijkl- ; 00000 
bcda ; 321 ; 22/12/1920 ; kyle  ; 0123514826 ; isaadgfa- ; 11111
```

I have to take the `;` only in the first line.

I know that the expression `(?<!\s+)^(.+)$` can catch only the first line, but I can't filter this line.

It's for a Java application, without code access.

Comment: Use `(?<=^.*);`, see https://regex101.com/r/geAYXD/1. Or, `\G[^;\v]*\K;`, see https://regex101.com/r/geAYXD/2. What is your regex flavor? Where are you using the regex?

Comment: I am using the regex in a Java application. 
Both of expressions that you answer didnt work in my case. 
Sorry for not explaining the right example

Im using this site for tests https://regexr.com/

Comment: regexr.com should NOT be used to test Java regexps. It does not support this flavor.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```java
\G([^;\r\n]*);
```

Replace with `$1` if you need to remove the semi-colons, or `$1<NEW_TEXT>` if you need to replace with some `NEW_TEXT`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/geAYXD/4).

*Details*:

- `\G` - start of string or the end of the previous successful match
- `([^;\r\n]*)` - Group 1 (`$1` in the replacement refers to the group value): any zero or more chars other than `;`, CR and LF chars
- `;` - a semi-colon.

Note that if you need to deal with any Unicode line break chars, you can use

```
\G([^;\r\n\x0B\x0C\u0085\u2028\u2029]*);
```